# How to pass php variable as value in store procedure call in sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am not getting any results while passing the values intot the stores procuder I have the code below

```
<?php

     $a="26456";

     $result3=mysql_query('CALL getItemStock($a)');
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    $result3=mysql_query('CALL getItemStock('.$a.')');
```

or

```
    $result3=mysql_query("CALL getItemStock($a)");
```

**UPDATE:**

If the parameter defined as string then you need to enclose it with quotes as well. For example:

```
    $a = 'I am String';
    $result3=mysql_query("CALL getItemStock('$a')");
```

However, if the parameter defined as number, then no quotation required.